# FileSystemWatcher not always firing

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

FileSystemWatcher works if I change the file with notepad.exe, but not if I change the file with VisualStudio. Why?
See also: [Powershell File Watcher Not Picking Up File Changes Made in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755816/powershell-file-watcher-not-picking-up-file-changes-made-in-visual-studio?rq=1)

```cs
static void FileWatcher()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"D:\Test\"),
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size,
        Filter = "file.txt",
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
    watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
}

static void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  Watcher:  {1}  {2}", DateTime.Now, e.ChangeType, e.FullPath);
}
```

PS. `watcher.Renamed` works. Thank you mjwills.

Comment: Visual Studio may delete and recreate. Can you track the other events to confirm?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following lines of code you should be able to capture all events.

```
watcher.Deleted += OnFileChanged;
watcher.Created += OnFileChanged;
```